# bitwise OR of uint16_t not returning a uint16_t

Tags: c++

Why does this static assertion fail?

```
static_assert(std::is_same<uint16_t, decltype(uint16_t(0)|uint16_t(0))>::value);
```

According to the Bitwise logic operators section of the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) on Arithmetic operators:

> Usual arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands and determine the type of the result."

Shouldn't this mean the bitwise OR of two `unsigned shorts` should be an `unsigned short`?

Comment: They should be `int`

Comment: Integral promotion converts `unsigned short` to `int`.

Comment: Just before that bit, "[...] before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)"

Comment: To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) 'In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments,'

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Not sure how I never noticed that before.